# How to compute MODE across combination of different fields in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table:

```
Broker      Currency    Ticker  Rate
Barclays    USD         Apple    0.10 
Barclays    USD         IBM      0.10 
Barclays    USD         Amazon   1.00 
Barclays    CAD         Col      0.50 
Barclays    CAD         Lyft     0.50 
Merrill     USD         Apple    0.20 
Merrill     USD         IBM      0.20 
Merrill     USD         Amazon   0.20 
Merrill     USD         Tesla    0.30 
Merrill     MXN         ticker1  5.30 
Merrill     MXN         ticker2  5.30 
Merrill     MXN         ticker3  2.60
```

I need to compute mode across each broker-currency field. Output:

```
Broker      Currency    Mode
Barclays    USD         0.1
Barclays    CAD         0.5
Merrill     USD         0.2
Merrill     MXN         5.3
```

Tried below:

```
select Count(*) as Frequency, rate as mode, date, name as Broker , ccy
FROM t
group by mode, date, Broker , ccy
order by Frequency
```

I am not sure how to find the mode once I have found the frequency.

Comment: Why not just use the [`mode()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) function?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I get this error: 'mode' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select name, ccy, rate,
             count(*) as frequency,
             row_number() over (partition by broker, currency order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by name, ccy, rate
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```